# How to get distance - MongoDB Template Near function

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to find Near by places. 
Below code is working fine.
But i'm not able to get actual distance of place from my given lat,lng.

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("coordinates")
    .near(new Point(searchRequest.getLat(),searchRequest.getLng()));

Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
query.addCriteria(criteriaName);
query.limit(5);
List<Place> ls = (List<Place>) mongoTemplate.find(query, Place.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [geoNear aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/). In spring-data-mongodb [GeoNearOperation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GeoNearOperation.html) is representing this aggregation.

Extend or create inherit `Place` class with field where you would like to have distance information (example with inheritance):

```
public class PlaceWithDistance extends Place {
    private double distance;

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(final double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

Instead of `Criteria` with `Query` use aggregation. Second argument of `geoNear` is name of field where distance should be set:

```
final NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery
    .near(new Point(searchRequest.getLat(), searchRequest.getLng()));
nearQuery.num(5);
nearQuery.spherical(true); // if using 2dsphere index, otherwise delete or set false

// "distance" argument is name of field for distance
final Aggregation a = newAggregation(geoNear(nearQuery, "distance"));

final AggregationResults<PlaceWithDistance> results = 
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(a, Place.class, PlaceWithDistance.class);

// results.forEach(System.out::println);
List<PlaceWithDistance> ls = results.getMappedResults();
```

Just to make it easier - associated imports:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.geoNear;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.newAggregation;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GeoNearOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.NearQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

Walery Strauch's example was useful for me...

However I wanted to :

- run aggregate query to get all the points in 2dsphere index with-in given distance in Kilometers or Meters. You can use Metrics.KILOMETERS & Metrics.MILES
- collection name is not specified as part of pojo

I have 2dsphere index with old way of representation in MongoDB. I am using Mongo as sharded databased for Geo-Spatial queries. My nearSphere query (without aggregation) was failing only when there is a shard key added into the same collection where I have 2dsphere index.

After using below implementation with shard key in the same collection. I am successfully able to fetch the required data.

Here is the sample :

```
import org.springframework.data.geo.Metrics;


final NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(new Point(longitude, latitude), Metrics.KILOMETERS)
        .num(limit)
        .minDistance(distanceInKiloMeters)
        .maxDistance(maxNearByUEDistanceInKiloMeters)
        .spherical(true);

final Aggregation a = newAggregation(geoNear(query, "distance"));

final AggregationResults<PlaceWithDistance> results = offlineMongoTemplate.aggregate(a, "myCollectionName", PlaceWithDistance.class);

final List<PlaceWithDistance> measurements = new ArrayList<PlaceWithDistance>(results.getMappedResults());
```