# Spring MongoDB get distance with NearQuery

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to get the distance in meters of different locations.

My query looks the following:

```
final NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(new org.springframework.data.geo.Point(longitude, latitude)).spherical(true);
final Aggregation a = newAggregation(geoNear(nearQuery, "distanceToNextVehicle"));
final AggregationResults<TrafficLight> results =
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(a, TrafficLight.class, TrafficLight.class);
List<TrafficLight> result = results.getMappedResults();
```

The problem is that as result for the distance (distanceToNextVehicle) I get wrong values. For example when I'm having `-101.29899` as longitude and `48.40227378` as latitude for the input in the query and in my database is one document with longitude `-101.29899` and latitude `48.4106602`. Then I'm getting as distance value `1.4637064145502492E-4` which translates to the real number of `0.00014637064145502492`, but what I should get is a value of `932.5`.

Relevant values from the TrafficLight class:

```
private org.springframework.data.geo.Point position;
private double distanceToNextVehicle;
```

As template for my implementation i used [How to get distance - MongoDB Template Near function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795980/how-to-get-distance-mongodb-template-near-function).

Comment: It looks like that distance is in radians - multiply by the radius of the Earth in meters to get the distance in meters.

Comment: That's it yes. Is this the default behavior? I did not find an example where the value is in radians.

Comment: It seems to behave differently when you query by just lat/long vs query with a geoJSON point, but I haven't found any clear documentation that says that.

Comment: There's a [Metrics and Distance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.geo-json.metrics) section in the Spring Data MongoDB reference documentation. Happy to extend it.